# Updating trigger frequency of Azure Logic App using API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to update the recurrence frequency and interval of a Logic App using [Azure Logic SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic/) and it is failing with this error message

> **Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException**: The request to patch workflow 'kk-test-logic-app' is not supported.
>   None of the fields inside the properties object can be patched.

Here is a code snippet showing what I am trying to do.

```
    var workflow = await _client.Value.Workflows.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, workflowName);

    dynamic workflowDefinition = workflow.Definition;
    workflowDefinition.triggers[triggerName]["recurrence"] = JToken.FromObject(new { frequency = triggerFrequency, interval = triggerInterval });

    await _client.Value.Workflows.UpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, workflowName, workflow);
```

where _client is `Lazy<LogicManagementClient>`.

Here is the definition of the trigger I am trying to update (got using Fiddler):

```
  "triggers": {
    "When_a_new_email_arrives": {
      "recurrence": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 2
      },
      "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?.value",
      "type": "ApiConnection",
      "inputs": {
        "host": {
          "api": {
            "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-southindia.azure-apim.net/apim/office365"
          },
          "connection": {
            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
          }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/Mail/OnNewEmail",
        "queries": {
          "folderPath": "Inbox",
          "importance": "Any"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that I am able to successfully retrieve the workflows, workflowRuns, workflowTriggers etc. Only the update operation is failing. Any ideas on how to update properties of workflows using the SDK?

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out by Amor-MSFT in the comments below, this is a defect and as a workaround, I am currently using CreateOrUpdateAsync instead of UpdateAsync. A [new defect](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3349) has been created in GitHub to get this to the attention of the SDK development team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The trigger currently executes every 30s checking if a new mail was received from a certain email address and is working well as expected. I'm trying to change the recurrence frequency from 30s to 2hours using the code I provided.

I created a mail trigger and I can reproduce the issue if I use invoke UpdateAsync method. According to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/Logic/Management.Logic/Generated/WorkflowsOperations.cs#L957) of Azure Logic C# SDK, it send a PATCH request which is not supported according the response message. After changed the HTTP method to PUT, I can update the workflow. Here is the sample code which I used to send the PUT request.

```
string triggerName = "When_a_new_email_arrives";
string resourceGroupName = "my resourcegroup name";
string workflowName = "my-LogicApp";
string subscriptionID = "my-subscriptionID";
var workflow = await _client.Workflows.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, workflowName);

string url = string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{2}?api-version=2016-06-01",
    subscriptionID, resourceGroupName, workflowName);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url);
message.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer put your token here");
message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
message.Headers.Add("Expect", "100-continue");

dynamic workflowDefinition = workflow.Definition;
workflowDefinition.triggers[triggerName]["recurrence"] = JToken.FromObject(new { frequency = "Minute", interval = 20 });

string s = workflow.ToString();
string workflowString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workflow, _client.SerializationSettings);

message.Content = new StringContent(workflowString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await client.SendAsync(message);
```

Comment: The trigger currently executes every 30s checking if a new mail was received from a certain email address and is working well as expected. I'm trying to change the recurrence frequency from 30s to 2hours using the code I provided. Note that this is only a POC that I'm doing and the production code will be lot different.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks for pointing me the problem in the source code. Looking at [CreateOrUpdateAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/Logic/Management.Logic/Generated/WorkflowsOperations.cs#L729), I can see that CreateOrUpdateAsync uses PUT HTTP method. Changing my code to use CreateOrUpdateAsync is now updating the recurrence frequency correctly.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your issue is solved, please mark helpful replies as answer. It will help others quick find and fix similar problem.

Comment: Created an issue for this defect in [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3349).